# Arranging Website All Content in <ul><li> is better from SEO Perspective?

Tags: html, seo, publishing

I am trying to do is to list the Latest News, and Latest Reviews on the Home/index page and a little bit confused what way should I use to list the content. Kindly tell me that which content publishing technique is better from SEO Perspective:

```
<div id="NewsList">
 <ul>
    <li><p>News1 Title</p><p>News1 Summary</p></li>
    <li><p>News2 Title</p><p>News2 Summary</p></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div id="NewsList">
  <div>
    <div id="NewsTitle">News1 Title</div>
    <div id="NewsSummary">News1 Summary</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div id="NewsTitle">News2 Title</div>
    <div id="NewsSummary">News2 Summary</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have published the Site Left and Top Menus in `<ul><li>` format. Plus Kindly tell me the better SEO Technique for Listing Products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **HTML5**, I'd go with:

```
<section>
  <h1>Latest News</h1>

  <article>
    <h1>News1 Title</h1>
    <p>News1 Summary</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h1>News1 Title</h1>
    <p>News1 Summary</p>
  </article>

</section>
```

If the "Latest News" and "Latest Reviews" are not the main content of the home/listing pages, you may want to use `aside` instead of `section`.

---

If you are using **HTML 4.01**, use the same structure but use `div` instead of `section`/`article`; also, adjust the heading levels, e.g.:

```
<div>
  <h2>Latest News</h2> <!-- depending on your page outline; adjust following levels accordingly -->

  <div>
    <h3>News1 Title</h3>
    <p>News1 Summary</p>
  </dov>

  <div>
    <h3>News1 Title</h3>
    <p>News1 Summary</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Im using XHTML 1.0 Transitional EN. What would u like to suggest for it? :-) thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nauman: XHTML 1.0 uses mostly the same semantics as HTML 4.01. So you can use the HTML 4.01 variant without having to change anything.